# Why is Farseer not working in Windows Phone 7/8?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I created a new Windows Phone Game (4.0) project in Visual Studio Express 2012 and added the Farseer project to the solution explorer. But adding a reference to the Farseer project is not working. I always get this error message:

A reference to 'Farseer Physics XNA WP7' could not be added. References with different refresh levels are not supported.

What is wrong? How can I use Farseer in Windows Phone 7/8?

I uploaded the two projects on pastebin.

Farseer project: pastebin.com/uyRusHxM

Windows Phone project: pastebin.com/s74Gr66y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If your project is 7.1 and Farseer is 7.0

Right click the Farseer project and click `Upgrade to Windows Phone 7.0`.

### If your project is 8.0 and Farseer is 7.1 or below

To upgrade to WP8.0 is more of a pita though not too bad.

You will need to edit the csproj file for both projects. So for both of them.

1. Right click the project in the solution explorer and select “Unload Project”.
2. Right click the project again and select “Edit csproj”.

This option is out of synch between the two projects. Find out the status of the `XnaRefreshLevel` tag in your project. I think it should be `<XnaRefreshLevel>1</XnaRefreshLevel>`. If so add that option under the same grouping in the farseer project. It may not be but the point is to make it so that the Farseer project has the same `XnaRefreshLevel` entry as your project.

Comment: I did the right click on the Farseer project but their is no 'Upgrade to Windows Phone 8.0'. What can I do?

Comment: Forgot that there was 8.0 now a days. Hopefully my edit helps.

Comment: I did the right click on the Farseer project but their is no 'edit solution file'. How can I edit the solution file?

Comment: Did you unload it first?

Comment: OK. I'm trying it.

Comment: I can't find <XnaRefreshLevel>1</XnaRefreshLevel>. I searched the whole 'Farseer Physics XNA WP7.csproj' What can I do?

Comment: I made a screenshot of Visual Studio: http://i39.tinypic.com/2zh4p53.png

Comment: Post both of your files on pastebin or something. Seeing the top 1/8 of a file isn't adequate for debugging.

Comment: I installed Windows 8 Pro with Parallels Desktop 8 on my iMac and then it works. But on the other hand, when I install Windows 8 Pro with Bootcamp I always get this error message: A reference to 'Farseer Physics XNA WP7' could not be added. References with different refresh levels are not supported. What can I do? What is different in Visual Studio 2012 on my Bootcamp partition? Why is my Visual Studio 2012 project not working on the Bootcamp partition?

Comment: Upload all of your csproj file on pastbin or something. There simply isnt enough info to debug it from what you are providing.

Comment: I uploaded the two projects on pastebin. Farseer project: http://pastebin.com/uyRusHxM   Windows Phone project: http://pastebin.com/s74Gr66y

Comment: Is something wrong with my project files?

Comment: I found the problem. The line <XnaRefreshLevel>1</XnaRefreshLevel> was missing in the Farseer project. @ClassicThunder Thanx for your help.

Comment: @Bryan Glad you found it, work apparently blocks pastebin and I do most of my GDSE at work so sorry about not getting to it.